# Get TD element from Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I am fetching values of debt to equity rations from a webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")

inputElement=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL'))) 
inputElement.send_keys('3IINFOTECH',Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#proceed-button'))).click()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
print("---")
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Financials").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ratios").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Leverage Ratios").click()
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='body']/table//thead/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
    print(elem.text)
except e:
    print(e)
```

I am not able to fetch the Debt to Equity (x) value of latest (Mar 2020) then clicking on Standalone and fetching the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the working code for the above problem. Enhance the code as per your need.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")

inputElement = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL')))
inputElement.send_keys('3IINFOTECH', Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#proceed-button'))).click()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
print("---")
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Financials").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ratios").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Leverage Ratios").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id=\"consolidated\"]/descendant::div[text()=\"Debt to Equity (x)\"]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]")
    print("Consolidated : " + elem.text)

    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Standalone").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ratios").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Leverage Ratios").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id=\"standalone\"]/descendant::div[text()=\"Debt to Equity (x)\"]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]")
    print("Standalone : " + elem.text)
except:
    print("Error Error Error")
```

Please mark it as answer if the problem is solved.

Comment: can get value of consolidated but in standalone it gives output as : Error Error Error

Comment: resolved the error, there is no ratio click in second time. thanks for your help. can you bit explain about this line bro - driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id=\"consolidated\"]/descendant::div[text()=\"Debt to Equity (x)\"]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]")
    print("Consolidated : " + elem.text)

Comment: would love to understand. will mark answer too

Comment: Actually if i will explain it will become very long. Better i will give you resource which you can see and read to get better understanding of Xpaths. First refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uktjWgKrtI&t=1873s youtube video and also read about xpath axes from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp. Do let me know if you need more explanation and dont forget to mark it as answer. :)